# PHP and Mysqli not retrieving a certain record

Tags: php, mysqli

Can someone help to figure out why this query will not work on retrieving a certain record from my database?

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$query1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `customer` WHERE `wmmw_domain` = '" . array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))) . "'"); 
      while($r = $query1->fetch_array()){

               $aff_id = $r['wmmw_id'];
  }
echo $aff_id;
```

This is the link for the test script:
http://evecournoyer.wm-mw.org/testindex.php

If I change one letter, or add a letter, to the database record
(such as evecournoyer1, or vecournoyer), it works.

Is there something in the name, evecournoyer, that prevents the
query from running? It's weird....

Here is one that works:
http://brucetherrien.wm-mw.org/testindex.php

Note: I can retrieve the record using Perl from a command shell, if it matters.

Comment: Try and add backticks around table and column names. This might not solve your problem but it will prevent a mysql reserved word error.

Comment: Added backticks, but still not working.... :(

Comment: what you're saying doesn't make sense... Also, I tried echoing out `array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])))` and it resulted in a warning. what happens if you change that code to `explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])[0]` ? (should result in same output. Tested on my domain)

Comment: The rendered output isn't very helpful. After your query, what does `$query1->num_rows` give? What about `$db->error`? If you echo out your query, what does that look like? What's your database structure and content?

Comment: Tried your changes Hallur, but still same results.

Comment: How do I echo out the query?

Comment: ... `var_dump($query1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [binding params](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and result.
Hopefully something like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, 'select name, id from mytable where myfield=?');
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $myValue);

$myValue = getSessionHttpHost();

/* bind result variables must match */
$stmt->bind_result($name, $id);

/* fetch values */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $id);
}

/* close statement and connection */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

......
```

I would check the data type, encoding and length for the offending field.

I presume you get results for other domains and so your http_host statement is working.

The adding or removing a char from the sub domain makes it work doesn't make sense. If the data type length was being exceeded and the stored value was truncated then I would expect it to fail the select condition but you are adding to it and it works.

I can't see anything in the sub domain that should fail. As suggested above viewing the query string might show up an anomaly in the where condition. Does the query fail if you run it manually through command prompt or client using the result of your http_host code for that domain?

Comment: They're using the `mysqli_` API to connect with and you're recommending they use `mysql_real_escape_string()`; you cannot mix different MySQL APIs. Plus, a prepared statement is better than `real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Ops missed the msqli.

Comment: Given there is no handling of the incoming http_host content I would still recommend using the alternatve, as kindly indicated by Fred -ii-, prepare() and bind_param() to sanatise what you receive and use in queries or save to the db.

Comment: just got back..... and yes, cmp, the other domains are working. I'll try these suggestions after dinner. Tx...

Comment: I tried adding 
    
var_dump($query1);

but I get no echo on the screen.

Comment: Ryan, all letters are lower case.
Going to try deleting the record and re-entering it.

Comment: Sorry, I do get a query dump if I use this URL:
http://brucetherrien.wm-mw.org/testindex.php

     object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(37) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } bt2

Blank screen when using http://evecournoyer.wm-mw.org/testindex.php

Comment: Searching for method of dumping sql from query or prepare statements returned an "it's not possible" result. Prepare() doesn't render the sql on the php side and there is no option to get it from query(). Only option seemed to be render it manually and escape values then print it. Other option was to use error handling to catch it.

Comment: Hmmm.... why would the brucetherrien query show the correct subdomain and ID, but the evecournoyer query shows wm-mw as the subdomain and no ID. I added some code to echo the http_host result. Also, if I run it from a command line, I get the ID for evecournoyer, no problem.

Comment: You could change the sub domain capture to a regex match using something like `/([a-z]*).wm-mw.org/i`. `$success = preg_match('/([a-z]*).wm-mw.org/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $match); if ($success){$subdomain =$match[1];}else{die('no sub domain.');}`

Comment: Thanks cmp, but I get "no sub domain". So I think I'll stop trying to figure this out and have it redirect to a different page if no subdomain record is found. Thanks to everyone else for helping.

Comment: You can use a regex test site to check the match expression against you host string to tweek it.